# How to create a ListView which can show details on the same activity?

Tags: android, listview

I'd like to create an Android app, there is a screen, which have a listview and when we click on the listItem, the screen will show the details of that listItem on the same activity (without start another). As the image below

[image]

Any idea is welcome, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Look into Fragments:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html

The Android developer site has training/tutorial/samples on this topic.

Comment: It's seem like what I'm looking for, but as I studied, this example is using FragmentActivity, which is not being used in Android 3.0 and up. And people use Fragment to do this instead, have any idea about it?

Comment: @QuáchThiên - The sample uses the Support Library which allows you to use Fragments on devices below 3.0. See: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Comment: thanks @Morrison, I got it, you've made my day

Answer (score 0):

Use an overlay. Put inside of frame layout your `ListView` and any other layout(the overlay) when both matches the parrent.
 
Set the visibility of the overlay to `GONE` and on list item click set it's visibly to `VISIBLE`.

So you have all the references to all your views.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can create a new `dialog` for displaying the details